# How do I include selectors in a theme for RStudio?

Tags: themes, rstudio

I have modified this [cobalt2 `.tmTheme`](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Cobalt2) and installed it for RStudio. I want to use some of the more granular features available for the [`.rsTheme` format](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html). When I go into the `.rsTheme` file generated by RStudio, I see many of the selectors described on [this site](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html#creating-an-rstheme), along with a number of additional selectors (complete list below), each followed by 1 or more declarations. I've figured out that these are [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp).

```
.ace_active_debug_line
.ace_active-line
.ace_bracket
.ace_comment
.ace_console_error
.ace_constant
.ace_constant.ace_language
.ace_constant.ace_numeric
.ace_cursor
.ace_editor
.ace_editor.ace_autocomplete
.ace_editor_theme
.ace_find_line
.ace_fold
.ace_foreign_line
.ace_gutter
.ace_gutter-active-line
.ace_invisible
.ace_keyword
.ace_keyword.ace_operator
.ace_layer
.ace_layer.ace_marker-layer
.ace_layer.ace_print-margin-layer
.ace_line
.ace_line-hover
.ace_marker-layer
.ace_markup.ace_heading
.ace_meta.ace_tag
.ace_print-margin
.ace_selected-word
.ace_selection
.ace_selection.ace_start
.ace_step
.ace_string
.ace_support.ace_function
.ace_support.ace_type
.ace_variable
.nocolor.ace_editor
.profvis-flamegraph
.rstudio-themes-flat
.rstudio-themes-flat.ace_editor_theme
.rstudio-themes-flat.editor_dark.ace_editor_theme
.rstudio-themes-flat.rstudio-themes-dark-menus
.terminal
.terminal.focus
.terminal.focus.xterm-cursor-style-bar
.terminal.xterm-cursor-style-block.focus
.terminal-cursor
.xtermBgColor0
.xtermBgColor1
.xtermBgColor10
.xtermBgColor100
.xtermBgColor101
.xtermBgColor102
.xtermBgColor103
.xtermBgColor104
.xtermBgColor105
.xtermBgColor106
.xtermBgColor107
.xtermBgColor108
.xtermBgColor109
.xtermBgColor11
.xtermBgColor110
.xtermBgColor111
.xtermBgColor112
.xtermBgColor113
.xtermBgColor114
.xtermBgColor115
.xtermBgColor116
.xtermBgColor117
.xtermBgColor118
.xtermBgColor119
.xtermBgColor12
.xtermBgColor120
.xtermBgColor121
.xtermBgColor122
.xtermBgColor123
.xtermBgColor124
.xtermBgColor125
.xtermBgColor126
.xtermBgColor127
.xtermBgColor128
.xtermBgColor129
.xtermBgColor13
.xtermBgColor130
.xtermBgColor131
.xtermBgColor132
.xtermBgColor133
.xtermBgColor134
.xtermBgColor135
.xtermBgColor136
.xtermBgColor137
.xtermBgColor138
.xtermBgColor139
.xtermBgColor14
.xtermBgColor140
.xtermBgColor141
.xtermBgColor142
.xtermBgColor143
.xtermBgColor144
.xtermBgColor145
.xtermBgColor146
.xtermBgColor147
.xtermBgColor148
.xtermBgColor149
.xtermBgColor15
.xtermBgColor150
.xtermBgColor151
.xtermBgColor152
.xtermBgColor153
.xtermBgColor154
.xtermBgColor155
.xtermBgColor156
.xtermBgColor157
.xtermBgColor158
.xtermBgColor159
.xtermBgColor16
.xtermBgColor160
.xtermBgColor161
.xtermBgColor162
.xtermBgColor163
.xtermBgColor164
.xtermBgColor165
.xtermBgColor166
.xtermBgColor167
.xtermBgColor168
.xtermBgColor169
.xtermBgColor17
.xtermBgColor170
.xtermBgColor171
.xtermBgColor172
.xtermBgColor173
.xtermBgColor174
.xtermBgColor175
.xtermBgColor176
.xtermBgColor177
.xtermBgColor178
.xtermBgColor179
.xtermBgColor18
.xtermBgColor180
.xtermBgColor181
.xtermBgColor182
.xtermBgColor183
.xtermBgColor184
.xtermBgColor185
.xtermBgColor186
.xtermBgColor187
.xtermBgColor188
.xtermBgColor189
.xtermBgColor19
.xtermBgColor190
.xtermBgColor191
.xtermBgColor192
.xtermBgColor193
.xtermBgColor194
.xtermBgColor195
.xtermBgColor196
.xtermBgColor197
.xtermBgColor198
.xtermBgColor199
.xtermBgColor2
.xtermBgColor20
.xtermBgColor200
.xtermBgColor201
.xtermBgColor202
.xtermBgColor203
.xtermBgColor204
.xtermBgColor205
.xtermBgColor206
.xtermBgColor207
.xtermBgColor208
.xtermBgColor209
.xtermBgColor21
.xtermBgColor210
.xtermBgColor211
.xtermBgColor212
.xtermBgColor213
.xtermBgColor214
.xtermBgColor215
.xtermBgColor216
.xtermBgColor217
.xtermBgColor218
.xtermBgColor219
.xtermBgColor22
.xtermBgColor220
.xtermBgColor221
.xtermBgColor222
.xtermBgColor223
.xtermBgColor224
.xtermBgColor225
.xtermBgColor226
.xtermBgColor227
.xtermBgColor228
.xtermBgColor229
.xtermBgColor23
.xtermBgColor230
.xtermBgColor231
.xtermBgColor232
.xtermBgColor233
.xtermBgColor234
.xtermBgColor235
.xtermBgColor236
.xtermBgColor237
.xtermBgColor238
.xtermBgColor239
.xtermBgColor24
.xtermBgColor240
.xtermBgColor241
.xtermBgColor242
.xtermBgColor243
.xtermBgColor244
.xtermBgColor245
.xtermBgColor246
.xtermBgColor247
.xtermBgColor248
.xtermBgColor249
.xtermBgColor25
.xtermBgColor250
.xtermBgColor251
.xtermBgColor252
.xtermBgColor253
.xtermBgColor254
.xtermBgColor255
.xtermBgColor26
.xtermBgColor27
.xtermBgColor28
.xtermBgColor29
.xtermBgColor3
.xtermBgColor30
.xtermBgColor31
.xtermBgColor32
.xtermBgColor33
.xtermBgColor34
.xtermBgColor35
.xtermBgColor36
.xtermBgColor37
.xtermBgColor38
.xtermBgColor39
.xtermBgColor4
.xtermBgColor40
.xtermBgColor41
.xtermBgColor42
.xtermBgColor43
.xtermBgColor44
.xtermBgColor45
.xtermBgColor46
.xtermBgColor47
.xtermBgColor48
.xtermBgColor49
.xtermBgColor5
.xtermBgColor50
.xtermBgColor51
.xtermBgColor52
.xtermBgColor53
.xtermBgColor54
.xtermBgColor55
.xtermBgColor56
.xtermBgColor57
.xtermBgColor58
.xtermBgColor59
.xtermBgColor6
.xtermBgColor60
.xtermBgColor61
.xtermBgColor62
.xtermBgColor63
.xtermBgColor64
.xtermBgColor65
.xtermBgColor66
.xtermBgColor67
.xtermBgColor68
.xtermBgColor69
.xtermBgColor7
.xtermBgColor70
.xtermBgColor71
.xtermBgColor72
.xtermBgColor73
.xtermBgColor74
.xtermBgColor75
.xtermBgColor76
.xtermBgColor77
.xtermBgColor78
.xtermBgColor79
.xtermBgColor8
.xtermBgColor80
.xtermBgColor81
.xtermBgColor82
.xtermBgColor83
.xtermBgColor84
.xtermBgColor85
.xtermBgColor86
.xtermBgColor87
.xtermBgColor88
.xtermBgColor89
.xtermBgColor9
.xtermBgColor90
.xtermBgColor91
.xtermBgColor92
.xtermBgColor93
.xtermBgColor94
.xtermBgColor95
.xtermBgColor96
.xtermBgColor97
.xtermBgColor98
.xtermBgColor99
.xtermBlink
.xtermBold
.xtermColor0
.xtermColor1
.xtermColor10
.xtermColor100
.xtermColor101
.xtermColor102
.xtermColor103
.xtermColor104
.xtermColor105
.xtermColor106
.xtermColor107
.xtermColor108
.xtermColor109
.xtermColor11
.xtermColor110
.xtermColor111
.xtermColor112
.xtermColor113
.xtermColor114
.xtermColor115
.xtermColor116
.xtermColor117
.xtermColor118
.xtermColor119
.xtermColor12
.xtermColor120
.xtermColor121
.xtermColor122
.xtermColor123
.xtermColor124
.xtermColor125
.xtermColor126
.xtermColor127
.xtermColor128
.xtermColor129
.xtermColor13
.xtermColor130
.xtermColor131
.xtermColor132
.xtermColor133
.xtermColor134
.xtermColor135
.xtermColor136
.xtermColor137
.xtermColor138
.xtermColor139
.xtermColor14
.xtermColor140
.xtermColor141
.xtermColor142
.xtermColor143
.xtermColor144
.xtermColor145
.xtermColor146
.xtermColor147
.xtermColor148
.xtermColor149
.xtermColor15
.xtermColor150
.xtermColor151
.xtermColor152
.xtermColor153
.xtermColor154
.xtermColor155
.xtermColor156
.xtermColor157
.xtermColor158
.xtermColor159
.xtermColor16
.xtermColor160
.xtermColor161
.xtermColor162
.xtermColor163
.xtermColor164
.xtermColor165
.xtermColor166
.xtermColor167
.xtermColor168
.xtermColor169
.xtermColor17
.xtermColor170
.xtermColor171
.xtermColor172
.xtermColor173
.xtermColor174
.xtermColor175
.xtermColor176
.xtermColor177
.xtermColor178
.xtermColor179
.xtermColor18
.xtermColor180
.xtermColor181
.xtermColor182
.xtermColor183
.xtermColor184
.xtermColor185
.xtermColor186
.xtermColor187
.xtermColor188
.xtermColor189
.xtermColor19
.xtermColor190
.xtermColor191
.xtermColor192
.xtermColor193
.xtermColor194
.xtermColor195
.xtermColor196
.xtermColor197
.xtermColor198
.xtermColor199
.xtermColor2
.xtermColor20
.xtermColor200
.xtermColor201
.xtermColor202
.xtermColor203
.xtermColor204
.xtermColor205
.xtermColor206
.xtermColor207
.xtermColor208
.xtermColor209
.xtermColor21
.xtermColor210
.xtermColor211
.xtermColor212
.xtermColor213
.xtermColor214
.xtermColor215
.xtermColor216
.xtermColor217
.xtermColor218
.xtermColor219
.xtermColor22
.xtermColor220
.xtermColor221
.xtermColor222
.xtermColor223
.xtermColor224
.xtermColor225
.xtermColor226
.xtermColor227
.xtermColor228
.xtermColor229
.xtermColor23
.xtermColor230
.xtermColor231
.xtermColor232
.xtermColor233
.xtermColor234
.xtermColor235
.xtermColor236
.xtermColor237
.xtermColor238
.xtermColor239
.xtermColor24
.xtermColor240
.xtermColor241
.xtermColor242
.xtermColor243
.xtermColor244
.xtermColor245
.xtermColor246
.xtermColor247
.xtermColor248
.xtermColor249
.xtermColor25
.xtermColor250
.xtermColor251
.xtermColor252
.xtermColor253
.xtermColor254
.xtermColor255
.xtermColor26
.xtermColor27
.xtermColor28
.xtermColor29
.xtermColor3
.xtermColor30
.xtermColor31
.xtermColor32
.xtermColor33
.xtermColor34
.xtermColor35
.xtermColor36
.xtermColor37
.xtermColor38
.xtermColor39
.xtermColor4
.xtermColor40
.xtermColor41
.xtermColor42
.xtermColor43
.xtermColor44
.xtermColor45
.xtermColor46
.xtermColor47
.xtermColor48
.xtermColor49
.xtermColor5
.xtermColor50
.xtermColor51
.xtermColor52
.xtermColor53
.xtermColor54
.xtermColor55
.xtermColor56
.xtermColor57
.xtermColor58
.xtermColor59
.xtermColor6
.xtermColor60
.xtermColor61
.xtermColor62
.xtermColor63
.xtermColor64
.xtermColor65
.xtermColor66
.xtermColor67
.xtermColor68
.xtermColor69
.xtermColor7
.xtermColor70
.xtermColor71
.xtermColor72
.xtermColor73
.xtermColor74
.xtermColor75
.xtermColor76
.xtermColor77
.xtermColor78
.xtermColor79
.xtermColor8
.xtermColor80
.xtermColor81
.xtermColor82
.xtermColor83
.xtermColor84
.xtermColor85
.xtermColor86
.xtermColor87
.xtermColor88
.xtermColor89
.xtermColor9
.xtermColor90
.xtermColor91
.xtermColor92
.xtermColor93
.xtermColor94
.xtermColor95
.xtermColor96
.xtermColor97
.xtermColor98
.xtermColor99
.xterm-cursor-blink-on
.xtermHidden
.xtermInvertBgColor
.xtermInvertColor
.xtermItalic
.xterm-selection
.xtermStrike
.xtermUnderline
.xterm-viewport
```

Are all of these declarations things I can safely change? Where can I find more detailed information about how to edit `.rsTheme` files and what type of feature each selector points to? Is there a way to include the selectors in the .tmTheme file, so that RStudio creates the ["generated values"](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html#creating-an-rstheme) automatically?